# ios application Localization

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, localization

How can I set ios application supported languages?
e.g I use NSDate to get current day. If the device language is other than my supported languages NSDateFormatter returns "day" in device's language but I want to get in English if I don't support that language.

I know there is a way to get day in specific language using NSLocal but I don't want to do that way because I need to convert other strings as well.

Answer (score 0):

The Apple [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/LocalizingYourApp/LocalizingYourApp.html) covers this pretty clearly. I know all you need is the word "day", but the following will help you include any word for any language if you do as follows:

1) You need to place all of the words (`String`s) in your application into a single `.swift` file. Each word should be returned in a function that converts this string into the localized string per the device's `NSLocal` set in the device settings:

```
struct Localization {
    static let all: String = {
        return getLocalized("All")
    }()
    static let allMedia: String = {
        return getLocalized("All Media")
    }()
    static let back: String = {
        return getLocalized("Back")
    }()

    // ...and do this for each string

}
```

2) This file should also contain a static function that will convert the string:

```
static func getLocalized(_ string: String) -> String {
    return NSLocalizedString(string, comment: "")
}
```

Here, the `NSLocalizedString(` method will do all of the heavy lifting for you. If will look into the `.XLIFF` file (we will get to that) in your project and grab the correct string per the device `NSLocale`. This method also includes a "comment" to tell the language translator what to do with the "string" parameter you passed along with it.

3) Reviewing all of the strings that you placed in your `.swift` file, you need to include each of those into an `.XLIFF` [file](http://www.noodlewerk.com/blog/using-xliff-for-localization-in-xcode/). This is the file that a language expert will need to go over and include the proper translated word per string in the `.XLIFF`. As I stated before, this is the file that once included inside your project, the `NSLocalizedString(` method will search this file and grab the correct translated string for you.

And that's it!

Comment: What if I need to get user's city using CLGeocoder. It returns user's city in a device language. I need to use only my supported languages.